# I cannot track referrer_install of google play

Tags: android, installation, referrer, flurry

I am trying to report the install event to flurry.

I have implemented ReferralReceiver to be called when the app is being installed.
I have all the parameters in a map.
I am calling Flurry using my flurry code:

```
FlurryAgent.onStartSession(context, FlurryCode);
FlurryAgent.logEvent("Referral", referralParams);
FlurryAgent.onEndSession(context);
```

The data is being stored to the SharedPreferences but it is not being sent to flurry.

Has anyone encountered this problem.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
     LogManager.Info("ReferralReceiver intent.action=" + intent.getAction());
     LogManager.Info("ReferralReceiver intent.DataString=" + intent.getDataString());
     LogManager.Info("ReferralReceiver intent.intent=" + intent.toString());

    // Workaround for Android security issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16006
    try
    {
        final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            extras.containsKey(null);
        }
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        return;
    }

    Map<String, String> referralParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // Return if this is not the right intent.
    if (! intent.getAction().equals("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER")) { //$NON-NLS-1$
        return;
    }

    String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    if( referrer == null || referrer.length() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    try 
    {
        referrer = URLDecoder.decode(referrer, "UTF-8");
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    LogManager.Info("ReferralReceiver intent.referrer=" + intent.getStringExtra("referrer"));

    SharedPreferences storage = context.getSharedPreferences(ReferralReceiver.PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = storage.edit();
    editor.putString("referrer", referrer);
    editor.commit();

    try {
        if (intent.hasExtra("referrer")) {
            String referrers[] = referrer.split("&");
            for (String referrerValue : referrers) 
            {
                String keyValue[] = referrerValue.split("=");
                if (keyValue.length==2)
                {
                    referralParams.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        LogManager.Error(e);
        return;
    }

    ReferralReceiver.storeReferralParams(context, referralParams);

    String FlurryCode = SaverrUtils.GetFlurryCode();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(context, FlurryCode);
    FlurryAgent.logEvent("Referral", referralParams);
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(context);
    LogManager.Info("New_Install");
}

public final static String PREFS_FILE_NAME = "ReferralParamsFile";


 /*
 * Stores the referral parameters in the app's sharedPreferences.
 * Rewrite this function and retrieveReferralParams() if a
 * different storage mechanism is preferred.
 */
public static void storeReferralParams(Context context, Map<String, String> params)
{
    SharedPreferences storage = context.getSharedPreferences(ReferralReceiver.PREFS_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = storage.edit();

    for(String key : SaverrUtils.EXPECTED_REFERRER_PARAMETERS)
    {
        String value = params.get(key);
        if(value != null)
        {
            editor.putString(key, value);
        }
    }

    editor.commit();
}



// Referral Parameters
public final static String[] EXPECTED_REFERRER_PARAMETERS = {
    "utm_source",
    "utm_medium",
    "utm_term",
    "utm_content",
    "utm_campaign",
    "referrer"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think flurry has a minimum amount of seconds between start/end session for it to actually count. You can save all the data to shared preference or file, then when the user starts your activity check if it's been given to flurry. If it's new do FlurryAgent.logEvent(...).